# IEEE Signal Processing Society membership

Tags: discussion

My university is having some problems with its IEEE membership since the beginning of the year and I was thinking about getting my own signal processing subscription for a while now but I'm not sure about the exact benefits.

How did it improve your research careers? Most articles I can get from arXiv, research gate or personal emails. Are there other inside benefits?

How is the community there? My signal processing group is rather small and the research topic (dictionary learning and sparse representation) is sort of narrow.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: discounts for conference fees

Comment: I think your research topic (dictionary learning and sparse representation) is not narrow because it is very hot.

Comment: Thank you, it might be hot but it is kind of hard to find a small community (even here) focusing on that. This site does not even have a tag for DL :)

Comment: @Paul Irofti Is it possible to share an email of yours?Don't even know if it is against the rules.

Comment: I am not sure if this question has an "objective" answer. Some may say it has helped them, others not. If you are in an academic position, I would say that it is a requirement. If you are a consultant it depends on what contracts do you go for. I would expect a journal reviewer to point out referencing towards "good" journals.

Comment: Yes, it does vary quite a bit as @A_A says.  Certainly academics (research students, post-docs, and professors) tend to benefit more as Laurent says in his answer.  In the US, it is definitely more professionally oriented, but that may just be my Section (Connecticut). Generally it's easy to get a copy of the table of contents of the latest journals; I'd just then email the authors for a copy of the paper.  That's often easier and cheaper than joining. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sole IEEE student membership cost about 30$, and the discount on conference fees is generally higher than this amount. The savings can even increase if you are a member of the society the conference belongs. You can receive IEEE Potentials Magazine and IEEE Spectrum Magazine, but the access to IEEExplore requires other subscription fees. So you won't get "more papers".

One of the interesting advantage is the @ieee.org email address, that "looks professional" and follows you if you change your location, so you can keep informed, and get reached. On a paper, it definitely seems more pro than someone@yahu.com. You can also access a network of other members though the IEEE app.

And if you start now and continue to be a member, one day you will be senior member (how posh) and, why not, be elected as a fellow!

Comment: Ya.  I joined 32 years ago this year, and I'm a senior member. :-)  Not sure I'll make Fellow, though, that seems to have a very high bar.

Comment: You remind me that I should apply for the seniority

Comment: if you need a sponsor, I'm happy to oblige.

Comment: How nice, let me fill the form soon